# Covariant Power Set Functor being injective on arrows.

Tags: category-theory

Consider the covariant power set functor
$$\mathcal{P}(A\xrightarrow{\ f\ }B) = \mathcal{P}A\xrightarrow{\ \mathcal{P}f\ }\mathcal{P}B$$
where $\mathcal{P}A$ is the power set of $A$, and for $X\subseteq A$, $\mathcal{P}f(X)$ is defined as:
$$\mathcal{P}f(X) = \{f(x)\ |\ x\in X \}.$$
Could someone explain why this is injective on morphisms? From my understanding, this means that for any two morphisms 
$$\mathcal{P}f,\mathcal{P}g,$$ 
if $\mathcal{P}f=\mathcal{P}g$, then $f=g$. Which would imply if $\mathcal{P}f$ and $\mathcal{P}g$  agree on all subsets of $A$, then $f=g$. Or, for all $X\subseteq A$ if $f(X)=g(X)$, then $f\equiv g$. However, I was told that the last sentence is not true in general, so there must be something I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: I think what you were told to be not true in general is simply that $f(X) = g(X)$ doesn't imply $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $f \neq g$, i.e. there is $x \in A$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$. Then 
$$\mathcal{P}f(\{x\}) = \bigl\{f(x') | x'\in\{x\}\bigr\} = \{f(x)\}$$
and
$$\mathcal{P}g(\{x\}) = \bigl\{g(x') | x'\in\{x\}\bigr\} = \{g(x)\}$$
but since $f(x)\neq g(x)$ these aren't the same, i.e. $\mathcal{P}f$ and $\mathcal{P}g$ disagree on $X = \{x\}$.

Comment: Ah, the injective on arrows makes perfect sense now. One last thing, how does the contrapositive of your statement differ from what I was told was wrong?

Comment: You mean, how is $\exists f\neq g \colon \mathcal{P}f = \mathcal{P}g$ different from $\exists f,g,X \colon f(X)=g(X) \wedge \exists x\in X: f(x)\neq g(x)$?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, I guess I was just asking if the statement: if for all $X \subseteq A $ , $f (X)=g (X) $ then $ f\equiv g $ is true

Comment: Yes, it is true. You can easily rephrase my proof to use these symbols.

Comment: That's a relief, I had constructed a similar argument earlier, thought I was missing something obvious. I really appreciate the help!